# Как Вконтакте защищается от размещения их видео на других сайтах? Как ухитряются их воровать?

Tags: алгоритм, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, видео

С помощью vk api можно получить ссылки на видео. Да и спарсить, вероятно не так сложно. Но ссылки на видеофайл в ВК, на сколько я знаю, динамические и вставить в свой плеер не выйдет. Каким образом получают видео на сайтах вроде вот этого: noodlemagazine.com (если погуглить, можно не один еще такой-же найти).
Если посмотреть в код, то ссылка на видео в плеере имеет вид вроде такого:

```
 adult.noodlemagazine.com/player/-187227252_456243012?m=c422f7ecf05ebe357ccbc0595833db3e&a=1
```

Выходит какой-то скрипт по стандартной ссылке из ВК вида

```
vk.com/video-187227252_456243012
```

, которую можно получить через api, получает ссылку на видеофайл и дальше отдает поток через себя в видеоплеер?

Правильно ли я понимаю то, как это все устроено? Это же какая нагрузка на сервер из-за  такого ретранслирования видео?  Как получают ссылку на видеофайл, там что куча проксей? Ведь ВК не должен позволять одному скрипту временные ссылки на кучу видеофайлов получать?  Может в api все-же есть способ получить временную ссылку на видеофайл(я не нашел)?

В общем, как такое проворачивают ?

Comment: Если скрипт с vk.com получает данные для видео, собирает их, и рендерит: значит это может сделать кто угодно, кто повторит логику скрипта vk.com . Но прямые ajax запросы не пройдут отсекутся через механизмы CORS . Поэтому будут проксироваться через собственный сервер - который для vk такой-же клиент, как аноним, или либо специально созданные сайтом-зеркальщиком аккаунты. Про производительность - на трансляции не так много и надо, толстый интернет-канал главное.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Правильно понимаю, что временная ссылка действительна только для запросившего ip, и потому нельзя получать временные ссылки сервером-зеркальщиком и их вставлять в плеер? Поэтому приходится пропускать поток через свой сервер?

Comment: нет. Ссылка, это ссылка на страницу, а не на видео. Но она содержит ID 187227252_456243012 . Почему там нельзя просто отобразить чужую страницу, а где-то можно: это уже регулируется на серверах самих vk, youtube, итд. То есть они смотрят не на IP ,  а на то что отправляет браузер клиента - а браузер чётко отправляет данные откуда(с какого дочернего домена) он пытается получить страницу, например в заголовке Origin и других Cors-заголовках. Отправку этой информации не обойти из браузера. А вот сервер - сам-себе браузер, он может что угодно отправлять в чистом виде.